# Is 多少个人 incorrect?

Tags: grammar, measure-word

I was studying Chinese grammar from a textbook. Somewhere in the book, it explains the difference between 几 and 多少. The book says that 几 needs a classifier. But using a classifier with 多少 is optional.
It also gives some examples, like
多少（张）照片，多少（个）朋友，多少（个）系
But when it reaches 人, it writes:
多少人 not 多少（个）人

I wonder if 多少个人 is incorrect or obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are correct. 多少个人 = 几个人. The latter is the same as 多少人, which is more common in daily use. 多少个人 is more of formal use.

Note that "个" shouldn't be used when you say/ask "多少位", which is identical to "几位". This phrase is more polite, especially for people in the position that provide services.

Answer (score 3):

多少个人 is not incorrect, just less common.  The "个" is indeed optional, so you can say either 多少人 or 多少个人.  Probably just an editing oversight in the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on context.

E.g. 多少人活着却如同死去. It's stilted to say 多少个人活着却如同死去.

你家里有多少人?  It's ok to say 你家里有多少个人?